# Python Library Turtle turtle.Terminator Error , can anyone explain it to me :(

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The code I'm use its from geekforgeeks website

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-snake-game-using-turtle-in-python/

And the error happen when im close the turtle windows
i have to do the answer in another question, but it still not work for me

the description of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:/Users/Zxed/Documents/1. DOCUMENT/Coding/Python/Game/snake.py", line 156, in <module>
        snake()
      File "c:/Users/Zxed/Documents/1. DOCUMENT/Coding/Python/Game/snake.py", line 88, in snake
        layar.update()
      File "C:\Users\Zxed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1303, in update
        t._update_data()
      File "C:\Users\Zxed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
        self.screen._incrementudc()
      File "C:\Users\Zxed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
        raise Terminator
    turtle.Terminator
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you provide some code on what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle.Terminator even after using exitonclick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534458/python-turtle-terminator-even-after-using-exitonclick)

Comment: @DiogoSilva the code im used https://pastebin.com/hPHFVcMf or from this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-snake-game-using-turtle-in-python/

Comment: @AnnZen eumm i have to try use turtleScreen._RUNNING = True, i put exactly in top op wn.mainloop(), but it still have that error

Answer (score 0):

The GeeksForGeeks example you cited is implemented poorly.  It uses `while True:` and `time.sleep(delay)` which have no place in an event-driven environment like turtle.  Turtle provides the `ontimer()` event to better handle this situation, which will allow you to exit the program cleanly.

Here's an [SO example with the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59430449/5771269) that you should have been able to find with a search.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with cdlane that GeeksForGeeks implementation is not an optimal implementation. However, considering it is a learning website and demonstrates a basic gamified learning code before you become expert in writing event-driven code (or even to test the difference between both), a potential workaround is instead of `while True:` you could use `while turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING==True` and enclose the rest of the loop routine within try except finally or try except. event-driven is the right way to go.

```
while turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING==True
    try:
        wn.update()
        ...
        ... 
        time.sleep(delay)
    except:
        pass #Or Exception handling
```

Since you have asked for an explanation, when you close the window the screen is not running and this makes the `turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING` flag to become false. During the next update this throws the Terminator error.